# get asp.net server and application url without a Request object

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to get the server url (ex: http://www.myapp.com:8080/applicationFolder) without having access to a **Request** object ?

I need the url at aplication_start and in some classes where the **Request** object with all the goodies is not available.

**note**: I know that getting the application folder can be done using

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
```

Comment: You may get virtual path using `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Request is a static property that always returns the Request object currently executing for the session.

I think all you need a custom solution to know when first request is made after application starts, and then you can send any email you want.. this is the similar problem with solution here http://weblogs.asp.net/reganschroder/archive/2008/07/25/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-application-start.aspx this do first initialization check in BeginRequest event.

Comment: Yes, but it is not available at application_start

Comment: But in application start there is not session initiated means no request. so why do you need the url here when no one has even requested a single page.. you should be using Session_start instead of application_start

Comment: I need it here because of some operations that should only be done once, at the start of the application (including logs). Also I know that a solution is to just save the string in web.config, but i think there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: but why would you need request url while initiating log data? there is no such relation between these two

Comment: Well, I have to send some notification emails just as the application starts. they need to contain the http://www.myapp.com:8080/applicationFolder path.

Comment: also, I don't consider this request information, since this is generic information, for all requests. I am sure that iis has it stored somewhere.

Comment: yes of course iis have it stored internally but i doubt it you have that much access to get that information from iis. of may be you will have to use WMI or something else to connect to iis and get the details.

Comment: seems there is no way to do this, I'll search a bit longer, if i don't find anything, I'll settle on this.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many different addresses all pointing to the same ASP.NET website, like using IP address or name. There might be more than 1 DNS name pointing to the same ASP.NET application. Therefore, HttpApplication, the parent class of Global, does not know which URL a visitor will use. Even IIS doesn't know. Therefore, you have to wait for the first request and then check in the request what URL the visitor uses to access your site. Something like this:

```
string baseUrl = Context.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

One has to use Context to get access to the Request during Global.Application_Start, because Global.Request is not initialised yet.